# Incompatible operand types ('char' and 'char *')?

Tags: c

Do anybody know what is wrong with this piece of code. it brings up the error above for. I'm trying to create a program that generates a "random" letter, and gives the user up to 6 chances to guess that letter.

`if ( Play != "y" || Play != "Y" )`

Edit: the full code

```
// This function displays game instructions, and returns nothing.
void Instructions();

// This function plays one game, and returns "W" if the player wins
// or "L" if the player runs out of guesses. 
char Play();

//this function prompts the player to make a guess and returns that guess
char getLetter();

//The function returns 1 if the guess matches the solution and returns a 0 if they do not match
char guess();

// This function returns a random letter between "A" and "Z 
char getAnswer();

int CompareLetters(char guess, char answer);

int main()
{ 

    char answer;


    //1. Greet the user and ask if they would like to play a guessing game.
    printf("\nHello there!\nWould like to play a guessing game?Enter Y or N: \n");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);

    if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        Instructions();
    {
        printf("\nYou entered Y.  Let's  play!\n");

        do{

        }while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');
    }
    printf("\nMaybe next time.\n");
    printf("\nGoodBye for now.\n");
    return -1;
} 


void Instructions()
{
    printf("I have a capital letter in mind. You have 6 chances to guess which letter I am \nthinking. I will let you know if you are too high or too low.\n");
    printf("After each guess, you will be informed if your guess is too high or too low.\nGood luck!\n");

}

int PlayGuess(char answer)
{
    int NumGuesses=0; int WinOrLose=0;

    while (NumGuesses < MAX_GUESSES && WinOrLose==0);
    {

        //6. If the player guesses wrong for a 6th time, console them and let the program end with a return code of 1.  
        char guess;
        guess = getLetter();
        CompareLetters(guess,answer);
        if(CompareLetters(guess,answer)==1)
        {
            WinOrLose = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            NumGuesses++;
        }
    }
    if (WinOrLose==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

//3. Generate a "random" character between 'A' and 'Z'.  This will be the value the player will try to guess. 
char getLetter()
{
    char guess=0;
    printf("Please enter your letter guess:", guess);
    scanf(" %c",&guess);
    return guess;
}

int CompareLetters(char guess, char answer)
{
    if(guess == answer)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ////5. If the player does not guess the right answer, display whether the guess is "too high" or "too low". 
        if (guess < answer)
        {
            printf("Your guess is too low.");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Your guess is too high.");
        }

        {
            printf("\nDo you want to play again? Y or N: \n");

        }
        if ( Play != 'y' &&  Play != 'Y' )
            printf("Thanks for playing.Goodbye!/n");
}
```

Comment: Where do you see this error?

Comment: if ( Play != "y" || Play != "Y" ),  "!" i keep getting the error operand types are incompatible ("char(*)()" and "char")

Answer (score 3):

`Play` appears to be a (single) `char`, not a `char` array.  So you should use `'y'` instead of `"y"`.

```
if ( Play != 'y' || Play != 'Y' )
```

There also seems to be a logic error here - presumably you meant to use `&&` rather than `||`:

```
if ( Play != 'y' && Play != 'Y' )
```

EDIT: You have now added the rest of the source code.  There are a *lot* of issues here, but I'll list a few to get you started.

- Your call to `Instructions()` is not inside the braces, so `Instructions()` will be called conditionally and the remaining code will execute *unconditionally*.

  ```
  if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
      Instructions();
  {
      printf("\nYou entered Y.  Let's  play!\n");
  ```

  This should be:

  ```
  if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
  {
      printf("\nYou entered Y.  Let's  play!\n");
      Instructions();
  ```
- Your `do {} while` statement is empty.  It's also an infinite loop, because your `scanf` for the answer is outside of the loop.

  ```
      do{

      }while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');
  ```

  You should move the `scanf` *inside* the loop, and add a call to `Play()`.
- The if statement comparing against `Play` in `CompareLetters` is both incorrect (there is no variable called `Play`) and in the wrong place (`CompareLetters` should not be responsible for this.)

  You should move this to `main` instead, updating and comparing against the `answer` variable as I mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah i change it from double to Single quotes but  the same problem is still occurring. The error operand types are incompatible ("char(*)()" and "char").

Comment: Ah, in that case it's because you have a _function_ called `Play` that you're trying to compare to.  Can you include the rest of the code in your question?

Answer (score 1):

In C, a sequence of characters in double quotes represents a string, which in memory is a `const char *`. Your variable `Play` contains a single `char` and isn't a `char*`. The way to tell the compiler to use a `char` constant is to use single quotes around your character like so:

```
Play != 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `Play` is taking char so try to use `''`. Also `""` are used for char* literals.You may try like this:

```
if ( Play != 'y' || Play != 'Y' )
```

instead of

```
 if ( Play != "y" || Play != "Y" )
```